# How automatic refresh data in web from JSON

Tags: jquery, json, refresh, setinterval

i have this code on my web to display some info from JSON, how can I automatic refresh element #last if JSON has changed? It´s possible display a countdown. I tried setInterval, but I´m not able to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("./last_match.php").done(function(data){
        $("#last").html(data);
    });  
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve this with:

```
var timeLeft = 60;// Start from countdown

    function timer() {
        var i = setInterval(function () {
            $('#time').text(timeLeft);
            if (timeLeft === 1) timeLeft = 61;//Reload start
            timeLeft--;
        }, 1000)
    }

    function loadlink(){
        $.get("./last_match.php").done(function(data){
            $("#last").html(data);
        }); 
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink();//This will run every 60 seconds
    }, 6000);

    timer();
```

last_match.php contains `<span id='time'>` that show countdown.

Thanks for read me.